# Finite field special functions

Tags: finite-fields, involutions

I am looking for special class of involutive functions (f) with exactly one (zero) fixed point over finite field $F_q$ with properties:

1) $f(f(x))=x$ for any $x \in F_q$ , $f(x)=x$ iff $x=0$

2)   For any fixed $a \in F_q$, $a \ne 0$ the following holds:

$f(x+a)-f(x)=g_a(x)$

where $g_a(x_1) \ne g_a(x_2) $ for any $x_1 \ne x_2$,
$x_1 \ne -a$ and $x_1 \ne 0$, $x_2 \ne -a$ and $x_2 \ne 0$

and

for any $x \ne -a$ and $x \ne 0$

$g_a(x) \ne a$

**EDIT(25 Aug 2019) I'd like to add 3'rd constraint**:

3)   For any fixed $a \in F_q$, $a \ne 0$ the following holds:

$f(x+a)-x=g_a(x)$

where $g_a(x_1) \ne g_a(x_2) $ for any $x_1 \ne x_2$,
$x_1 \ne -a$ and $x_1 \ne 0$, $x_2 \ne -a$ and $x_2 \ne 0$

Comment: Actually 3'rd constraint directly follows from 1 and 2.

Answer (score 5):

An involution with exactly one fixed point must be over an odd-sized set, so characteristic 2 is ruled out.

By my computation, there are only three such functions for odd prime powers between 3 and 29 inclusive:

- $f_1: GF(3) \to GF(3)$ given in cycle form as $(0)(12)$
- $f_2: GF(7) \to GF(7)$ is $(0)(13)(26)(45)$
- $f_3: GF(7) \to GF(7)$ is $(0)(15)(23)(46)$ (so $f_3(x) = -f_2(-x)$ and there's fundamentally only one solution for $GF(7)$).

However, $GF(31)$ has three pairs:

```
0, 12, 24, 8, 17, 28, 16, 9, 3, 7, 25, 30, 1, 27, 18, 21, 6, 4, 14, 20, 19, 15, 29, 26, 2, 10, 23, 13, 5, 22, 11
0, 13, 26, 23, 21, 7, 15, 5, 11, 25, 14, 8, 30, 1, 10, 6, 22, 27, 19, 18, 28, 4, 16, 3, 29, 9, 2, 17, 20, 24, 12
0, 14, 28, 5, 25, 3, 10, 16, 19, 24, 6, 23, 20, 30, 1, 22, 7, 18, 17, 8, 12, 27, 15, 11, 9, 4, 29, 21, 2, 26, 13
0, 18, 5, 29, 10, 2, 27, 22, 20, 16, 4, 19, 23, 14, 13, 24, 9, 30, 1, 11, 8, 25, 7, 12, 15, 21, 28, 6, 26, 3, 17
0, 19, 7, 11, 14, 29, 22, 2, 28, 15, 27, 3, 13, 12, 4, 9, 25, 21, 30, 1, 23, 17, 6, 20, 26, 16, 24, 10, 8, 5, 18
0, 20, 9, 26, 18, 8, 21, 29, 5, 2, 16, 12, 11, 17, 27, 25, 10, 13, 4, 30, 1, 6, 24, 28, 22, 15, 3, 14, 23, 7, 19
```

My search strategy is to enumerate involutions by maintaining a set of unpaired elements, from which I take the smallest and one other, check for failure of injection in any $g_a$, and then recurse.

---

I note that nothing in the definition (functions which are involutions and perfect nonlinear) relies on the multiplicative structure of $GF(q)$, and the additive structure of $GF(p)$ (for $p$ prime) is just the additive structure of $\mathbb{Z} / p\mathbb{Z}$.

I note that the three fields for which I have found solutions have orders which are Mersenne primes. I therefore extended my search to $\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z}$ for the Mersenne number $n=15$, and found one pair of solutions:

```
0, 4, 8, 14, 1, 10, 13, 9, 2, 7, 5, 12, 11, 6, 3
0, 12, 9, 4, 3, 10, 8, 13, 6, 2, 5, 14, 1, 7, 11
```

I further observe that all of the functions I've found so far are exponential, in the sense that they satisfy $f(2x) = 2f(x)$. By restricting the search to involutions which satisfy this criterion, I am able to extend it to higher Mersenne numbers, finding for $n=63$ the functions

```
0, 6, 12, 32, 24, 62, 1, 26, 48, 45, 61, 25, 2, 35, 52, 23, 33, 47, 27, 56, 59, 42, 50, 15, 4, 11, 7, 18, 41, 60, 46, 34, 3, 16, 31, 13, 54, 44, 49, 43, 55, 28, 21, 39, 37, 9, 30, 17, 8, 38, 22, 53, 14, 51, 36, 40, 19, 58, 57, 20, 29, 10, 5
0, 8, 16, 53, 32, 38, 43, 62, 1, 45, 13, 51, 23, 10, 61, 44, 2, 41, 27, 34, 26, 42, 39, 12, 46, 30, 20, 18, 59, 48, 25, 35, 4, 58, 19, 31, 54, 57, 5, 22, 52, 17, 21, 6, 15, 9, 24, 49, 29, 47, 60, 11, 40, 3, 36, 56, 55, 37, 33, 28, 50, 14, 7
0, 25, 50, 55, 37, 40, 47, 53, 11, 27, 17, 8, 31, 15, 43, 13, 22, 10, 54, 51, 34, 42, 16, 28, 62, 1, 30, 9, 23, 49, 26, 12, 44, 59, 20, 58, 45, 4, 39, 38, 5, 57, 21, 14, 32, 36, 56, 6, 61, 29, 2, 19, 60, 7, 18, 3, 46, 41, 35, 33, 52, 48, 24
0, 39, 15, 11, 30, 28, 22, 17, 60, 45, 56, 3, 44, 61, 34, 2, 57, 7, 27, 31, 49, 42, 6, 58, 25, 24, 59, 18, 5, 43, 4, 19, 51, 37, 14, 40, 54, 33, 62, 1, 35, 47, 21, 29, 12, 9, 53, 41, 50, 20, 48, 32, 55, 46, 36, 52, 10, 16, 23, 26, 8, 13, 38
0, 56, 49, 13, 35, 30, 26, 8, 7, 27, 60, 23, 52, 3, 16, 34, 14, 39, 54, 48, 57, 42, 46, 11, 41, 58, 6, 9, 32, 44, 5, 59, 28, 38, 15, 4, 45, 43, 33, 17, 51, 24, 21, 37, 29, 36, 22, 61, 19, 2, 53, 40, 12, 50, 18, 62, 1, 20, 25, 31, 10, 47, 55
0, 58, 53, 34, 43, 6, 5, 44, 23, 27, 12, 49, 10, 41, 25, 55, 46, 33, 54, 26, 24, 42, 35, 8, 20, 14, 19, 9, 50, 32, 47, 60, 29, 17, 3, 22, 45, 56, 52, 59, 48, 13, 21, 4, 7, 36, 16, 30, 40, 11, 28, 61, 38, 2, 18, 15, 37, 62, 1, 39, 31, 51, 57
```

and for $n=127$

```
0, 7, 14, 63, 28, 54, 126, 1, 56, 90, 108, 87, 125, 55, 2, 31, 112, 43, 53, 29, 89, 57, 47, 82, 123, 105, 110, 66, 4, 19, 62, 15, 97, 77, 86, 109, 106, 46, 58, 100, 51, 75, 114, 17, 94, 68, 37, 22, 119, 122, 83, 40, 93, 18, 5, 13, 8, 21, 38, 104, 124, 88, 30, 3, 67, 95, 27, 64, 45, 107, 91, 79, 85, 78, 92, 41, 116, 33, 73, 71, 102, 118, 23, 50, 101, 72, 34, 11, 61, 20, 9, 70, 74, 52, 44, 65, 111, 32, 117, 103, 39, 84, 80, 99, 59, 25, 36, 69, 10, 35, 26, 96, 16, 115, 42, 113, 76, 98, 81, 48, 121, 120, 49, 24, 60, 12, 6
0, 10, 20, 92, 40, 64, 57, 85, 80, 126, 1, 82, 114, 25, 43, 105, 33, 111, 125, 81, 2, 88, 37, 96, 101, 13, 50, 79, 86, 113, 83, 54, 66, 16, 95, 38, 123, 22, 35, 60, 4, 69, 49, 14, 74, 56, 65, 55, 75, 42, 26, 121, 100, 97, 31, 47, 45, 6, 99, 122, 39, 93, 108, 68, 5, 46, 32, 106, 63, 41, 76, 116, 119, 104, 44, 48, 70, 103, 120, 27, 8, 19, 11, 30, 98, 7, 28, 91, 21, 124, 112, 87, 3, 61, 110, 34, 23, 53, 84, 58, 52, 24, 115, 77, 73, 15, 67, 109, 62, 107, 94, 17, 90, 29, 12, 102, 71, 118, 117, 72, 78, 51, 59, 36, 89, 18, 9
0, 14, 28, 37, 56, 105, 74, 64, 112, 115, 83, 77, 21, 126, 1, 23, 97, 62, 103, 107, 39, 12, 27, 15, 42, 94, 125, 22, 2, 80, 46, 72, 67, 58, 124, 95, 79, 3, 87, 20, 78, 96, 24, 91, 54, 110, 30, 76, 84, 89, 61, 98, 123, 59, 44, 86, 4, 120, 33, 53, 92, 50, 17, 70, 7, 82, 116, 32, 121, 102, 63, 75, 31, 117, 6, 71, 47, 11, 40, 36, 29, 111, 65, 10, 48, 109, 55, 38, 108, 49, 93, 43, 60, 90, 25, 35, 41, 16, 51, 101, 122, 99, 69, 18, 119, 5, 118, 19, 88, 85, 45, 81, 8, 114, 113, 9, 66, 73, 106, 104, 57, 68, 100, 52, 34, 26, 13
0, 19, 38, 13, 76, 62, 26, 44, 25, 63, 124, 97, 52, 3, 88, 84, 50, 119, 126, 1, 121, 99, 67, 47, 104, 8, 6, 59, 49, 85, 41, 66, 100, 79, 111, 96, 125, 120, 2, 53, 115, 30, 71, 58, 7, 105, 94, 23, 81, 28, 16, 55, 12, 39, 118, 51, 98, 122, 43, 27, 82, 92, 5, 9, 73, 70, 31, 22, 95, 112, 65, 42, 123, 64, 113, 87, 4, 93, 106, 33, 103, 48, 60, 90, 15, 29, 116, 75, 14, 91, 83, 89, 61, 77, 46, 68, 35, 11, 56, 21, 32, 107, 110, 80, 24, 45, 78, 101, 109, 108, 102, 34, 69, 74, 117, 40, 86, 114, 54, 17, 37, 20, 57, 72, 10, 36, 18
0, 21, 42, 30, 84, 95, 60, 19, 41, 22, 63, 68, 120, 118, 38, 65, 82, 98, 44, 7, 126, 1, 9, 78, 113, 56, 109, 124, 76, 46, 3, 102, 37, 119, 69, 93, 88, 32, 14, 75, 125, 8, 2, 47, 18, 61, 29, 43, 99, 72, 112, 79, 91, 117, 121, 104, 25, 116, 92, 70, 6, 45, 77, 10, 74, 15, 111, 73, 11, 34, 59, 96, 49, 67, 64, 39, 28, 62, 23, 51, 123, 110, 16, 101, 4, 87, 94, 85, 36, 103, 122, 52, 58, 35, 86, 5, 71, 100, 17, 48, 97, 83, 31, 89, 55, 114, 107, 106, 115, 26, 81, 66, 50, 24, 105, 108, 57, 53, 13, 33, 12, 54, 90, 80, 27, 40, 20
0, 31, 62, 7, 124, 82, 14, 3, 121, 44, 37, 34, 28, 91, 6, 63, 115, 69, 88, 106, 74, 40, 68, 116, 56, 86, 55, 117, 12, 101, 126, 1, 103, 84, 11, 118, 49, 10, 85, 57, 21, 66, 80, 76, 9, 50, 105, 89, 112, 36, 45, 94, 110, 73, 107, 26, 24, 39, 75, 81, 125, 102, 2, 15, 79, 67, 41, 65, 22, 17, 109, 95, 98, 53, 20, 58, 43, 122, 114, 64, 42, 59, 5, 92, 33, 38, 25, 108, 18, 47, 100, 13, 83, 104, 51, 71, 97, 96, 72, 111, 90, 29, 61, 32, 93, 46, 19, 54, 87, 70, 52, 99, 48, 119, 78, 16, 23, 27, 35, 113, 123, 8, 77, 120, 4, 60, 30
0, 39, 78, 109, 29, 104, 91, 101, 58, 74, 81, 27, 55, 80, 75, 107, 116, 41, 21, 63, 35, 18, 54, 28, 110, 123, 33, 11, 23, 4, 87, 90, 105, 26, 82, 20, 42, 68, 126, 1, 70, 17, 36, 115, 108, 79, 56, 60, 93, 51, 119, 49, 66, 62, 22, 12, 46, 97, 8, 96, 47, 113, 53, 19, 83, 118, 52, 114, 37, 77, 40, 117, 84, 95, 9, 14, 125, 69, 2, 45, 13, 10, 34, 64, 72, 121, 103, 30, 89, 88, 31, 6, 112, 48, 120, 73, 59, 57, 102, 122, 111, 7, 98, 86, 5, 32, 124, 15, 44, 3, 24, 100, 92, 61, 67, 43, 16, 71, 65, 50, 94, 85, 99, 25, 106, 76, 38
0, 41, 82, 73, 37, 111, 19, 36, 74, 97, 95, 110, 38, 121, 72, 83, 21, 28, 67, 6, 63, 16, 93, 102, 76, 48, 115, 92, 17, 120, 39, 81, 42, 123, 56, 62, 7, 4, 12, 30, 126, 1, 32, 107, 59, 47, 77, 45, 25, 109, 96, 75, 103, 61, 57, 69, 34, 54, 113, 44, 78, 53, 35, 20, 84, 100, 119, 18, 112, 55, 124, 105, 14, 3, 8, 51, 24, 46, 60, 104, 125, 31, 2, 15, 64, 117, 87, 86, 118, 101, 94, 98, 27, 22, 90, 10, 50, 9, 91, 116, 65, 89, 23, 52, 79, 71, 122, 43, 114, 49, 11, 5, 68, 58, 108, 26, 99, 85, 88, 66, 29, 13, 106, 33, 70, 80, 40
0, 55, 110, 88, 93, 97, 49, 20, 59, 25, 67, 48, 98, 120, 40, 81, 118, 19, 50, 17, 7, 83, 96, 94, 69, 9, 113, 63, 80, 41, 35, 53, 109, 56, 38, 30, 100, 116, 34, 42, 14, 29, 39, 121, 65, 103, 61, 75, 11, 6, 18, 119, 99, 31, 126, 1, 33, 117, 82, 8, 70, 46, 106, 27, 91, 44, 112, 10, 76, 24, 60, 104, 73, 72, 105, 47, 68, 95, 84, 90, 28, 15, 58, 21, 78, 124, 115, 101, 3, 123, 79, 64, 122, 4, 23, 77, 22, 5, 12, 52, 36, 87, 111, 45, 71, 74, 62, 114, 125, 32, 2, 102, 66, 26, 107, 86, 37, 57, 16, 51, 13, 43, 92, 89, 85, 108, 54
0, 73, 19, 42, 38, 35, 84, 114, 76, 111, 70, 90, 41, 20, 101, 61, 25, 125, 95, 2, 13, 65, 53, 56, 82, 16, 40, 91, 75, 115, 122, 105, 50, 104, 123, 5, 63, 48, 4, 124, 26, 12, 3, 49, 106, 69, 112, 99, 37, 43, 32, 59, 80, 22, 55, 54, 23, 67, 103, 51, 117, 15, 83, 36, 100, 21, 81, 57, 119, 45, 10, 94, 126, 1, 96, 28, 8, 109, 121, 116, 52, 66, 24, 62, 6, 88, 98, 113, 85, 93, 11, 27, 97, 89, 71, 18, 74, 92, 86, 47, 64, 14, 118, 58, 33, 31, 44, 120, 110, 77, 108, 9, 46, 87, 7, 29, 79, 60, 102, 68, 107, 78, 30, 34, 39, 17, 72
0, 87, 47, 57, 94, 21, 114, 98, 61, 39, 42, 28, 101, 19, 69, 59, 122, 116, 78, 13, 84, 5, 56, 48, 75, 104, 38, 62, 11, 36, 118, 77, 117, 37, 105, 100, 29, 33, 26, 9, 41, 40, 10, 63, 112, 125, 96, 2, 23, 67, 81, 103, 76, 119, 124, 113, 22, 3, 72, 15, 109, 8, 27, 43, 107, 92, 74, 49, 83, 14, 73, 93, 58, 70, 66, 24, 52, 31, 18, 102, 82, 50, 80, 68, 20, 95, 126, 1, 97, 115, 123, 120, 65, 71, 4, 85, 46, 88, 7, 110, 35, 12, 79, 51, 25, 34, 111, 64, 121, 60, 99, 106, 44, 55, 6, 89, 17, 32, 30, 53, 91, 108, 16, 90, 54, 45, 86
0, 89, 51, 21, 102, 28, 42, 33, 77, 62, 56, 111, 84, 60, 66, 35, 27, 103, 124, 83, 112, 3, 95, 122, 41, 29, 120, 16, 5, 25, 70, 68, 54, 7, 79, 15, 121, 96, 39, 38, 97, 24, 6, 55, 63, 93, 117, 114, 82, 125, 58, 2, 113, 118, 32, 43, 10, 87, 50, 90, 13, 75, 9, 44, 108, 74, 14, 80, 31, 119, 30, 81, 115, 105, 65, 61, 78, 8, 76, 34, 67, 71, 48, 19, 12, 91, 110, 57, 126, 1, 59, 85, 107, 45, 101, 22, 37, 40, 123, 104, 116, 94, 4, 17, 99, 73, 109, 92, 64, 106, 86, 11, 20, 52, 47, 72, 100, 46, 53, 69, 26, 36, 23, 98, 18, 49, 88
0, 97, 67, 123, 7, 50, 119, 4, 14, 92, 100, 104, 111, 49, 8, 79, 28, 75, 57, 40, 73, 108, 81, 34, 95, 66, 98, 37, 16, 55, 31, 30, 56, 76, 23, 44, 114, 27, 80, 109, 19, 102, 89, 94, 35, 122, 68, 85, 63, 13, 5, 84, 69, 107, 74, 29, 32, 18, 110, 105, 62, 86, 60, 48, 112, 125, 25, 2, 46, 52, 88, 103, 101, 20, 54, 17, 33, 82, 91, 15, 38, 22, 77, 118, 51, 47, 61, 106, 70, 42, 117, 78, 9, 116, 43, 24, 126, 1, 26, 115, 10, 72, 41, 71, 11, 59, 87, 53, 21, 39, 58, 12, 64, 121, 36, 99, 93, 90, 83, 6, 124, 113, 45, 3, 120, 65, 96
0, 107, 87, 100, 47, 37, 73, 115, 94, 114, 74, 70, 19, 22, 103, 77, 61, 46, 101, 12, 21, 20, 13, 72, 38, 96, 44, 30, 79, 110, 27, 56, 122, 41, 92, 69, 75, 5, 24, 91, 42, 33, 40, 123, 26, 111, 17, 4, 76, 104, 65, 99, 88, 63, 60, 78, 31, 68, 93, 116, 54, 16, 112, 53, 117, 50, 82, 121, 57, 35, 11, 102, 23, 6, 10, 36, 48, 15, 55, 28, 84, 98, 66, 109, 80, 125, 119, 2, 52, 113, 95, 39, 34, 58, 8, 90, 25, 124, 81, 51, 3, 18, 71, 14, 49, 118, 126, 1, 120, 83, 29, 45, 62, 89, 9, 7, 59, 64, 105, 86, 108, 67, 32, 43, 97, 85, 106
0, 109, 91, 117, 55, 70, 107, 90, 110, 73, 13, 41, 87, 10, 53, 58, 93, 25, 19, 18, 26, 49, 82, 103, 47, 17, 20, 95, 106, 71, 116, 92, 59, 81, 50, 66, 38, 44, 36, 113, 52, 11, 98, 112, 37, 67, 79, 24, 94, 21, 34, 123, 40, 14, 63, 4, 85, 62, 15, 32, 105, 96, 57, 54, 118, 122, 35, 45, 100, 84, 5, 29, 76, 9, 88, 115, 72, 111, 99, 46, 104, 33, 22, 120, 69, 56, 97, 12, 74, 125, 7, 2, 31, 16, 48, 27, 61, 86, 42, 78, 68, 121, 119, 23, 80, 60, 28, 6, 126, 1, 8, 77, 43, 39, 124, 75, 30, 3, 64, 102, 83, 101, 65, 51, 114, 89, 108
0, 114, 101, 93, 75, 27, 59, 70, 23, 21, 54, 61, 118, 14, 13, 119, 46, 82, 42, 39, 108, 9, 122, 8, 109, 58, 28, 5, 26, 76, 111, 86, 92, 102, 37, 67, 84, 34, 78, 19, 89, 72, 18, 79, 117, 62, 16, 98, 91, 87, 116, 80, 56, 121, 10, 96, 52, 64, 25, 6, 95, 11, 45, 120, 57, 110, 77, 35, 74, 94, 7, 123, 41, 83, 68, 4, 29, 66, 38, 43, 51, 97, 17, 73, 36, 103, 31, 49, 107, 40, 124, 48, 32, 3, 69, 60, 55, 81, 47, 125, 105, 2, 33, 85, 112, 100, 115, 88, 20, 24, 65, 30, 104, 126, 1, 106, 50, 44, 12, 15, 63, 53, 22, 71, 90, 99, 113
0, 118, 109, 38, 91, 68, 76, 49, 55, 10, 9, 56, 25, 115, 98, 37, 110, 33, 20, 65, 18, 60, 112, 54, 50, 12, 103, 75, 69, 43, 74, 104, 93, 17, 66, 124, 40, 15, 3, 106, 36, 99, 120, 29, 97, 116, 108, 119, 100, 7, 24, 57, 79, 83, 23, 8, 11, 51, 86, 64, 21, 95, 81, 122, 59, 19, 34, 88, 5, 28, 121, 82, 80, 96, 30, 27, 6, 101, 85, 52, 72, 62, 71, 53, 113, 78, 58, 123, 67, 92, 105, 4, 89, 32, 111, 61, 73, 44, 14, 41, 48, 77, 114, 26, 31, 90, 39, 125, 46, 2, 16, 94, 22, 84, 102, 13, 45, 126, 1, 47, 42, 70, 63, 87, 35, 107, 117
0, 121, 115, 67, 103, 78, 7, 6, 79, 46, 29, 51, 14, 85, 12, 111, 31, 101, 92, 117, 58, 91, 102, 68, 28, 47, 43, 88, 24, 10, 95, 16, 62, 83, 75, 53, 57, 118, 107, 66, 116, 93, 55, 26, 77, 104, 9, 25, 56, 54, 94, 11, 86, 35, 49, 42, 48, 36, 20, 82, 63, 100, 32, 60, 124, 97, 39, 3, 23, 89, 106, 119, 114, 122, 109, 34, 87, 44, 5, 8, 105, 90, 59, 33, 110, 13, 52, 76, 27, 69, 81, 21, 18, 41, 50, 30, 112, 65, 108, 123, 61, 17, 22, 4, 45, 80, 70, 38, 98, 74, 84, 15, 96, 125, 72, 2, 40, 19, 37, 71, 126, 1, 73, 99, 64, 113, 120
```

I think there is starting to be sufficient evidence to conjecture that all Mersenne numbers $n$ will have involutive perfect nonlinear exponential functions over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, and for Mersenne primes these will be involutive perfect nonlinear functions over $GF(n)$.

Comment: Good idea to use algorithmic approach, great results !!!
I tried to find using mathematical abstractions.

Comment: Incidentally, since there's no use of multiplication in the definition of these functions, it just occurred to me to try searching for suitable functions over $Z_{15}$, and there is one pair, with representative $0(1,4)(2,8)(3,14)(5,10)(6,13)(7,9)(11,12)$.

Comment: Hmm. These examples are all exponential (specifically, $f(2x) = 2f(x)$). I should be able to enumerate exponential functions much more efficiently, so I can check whether this class extends to $GF(127)$...

Comment: Little note:
all of such functions produces starter.
I'd give the name for such starter.

Comment: Amazing result !!

Comment: Can ask you to shared your search algorithm in some programming language ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pjt33/42a3bd6eaae04b8f74163825021a9d03

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: I see the following output for GF(7):
0, 3, 6, 1, 5, 4, 2
It is either by bug or I can't read this line

Comment: @user144684, that's $f(0), f(1), f(2), \ldots, f(6)$.

Comment: Running 37 minutes GF(31) - 0 results for now

Comment: I am trying to understand why (0) (13) (26) (45)
is exponential.
which multiplier works here ?

Comment: @user144684, I'm not sure what misfire of the brain caused me to see that as an exponential relationship. Trying to find the appropriate term to correct it to.

Comment: Actually  (0) (13) (26) (45) is exponential
with multiplier 2
I checked

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for are called *perfect nonlinear* or differentially $1-$uniform functions.

They don't exist over even characteristic since if $x_0$ satisfies
$$
f(x+a)-f(x)=b,
$$
so does $x_0+a.$

For a long time only some power functions or functions equivalent to them were known. A recent paper lists
the following known examples among others.

$$x^2~~ in ~~GF(p^n), $$

$$x^{p^k+1} ~~in ~~GF(p^n),\quad k \leq n/2~~and ~~n/(k,n)~~odd$$

$$x^{10} + x^6 − x^2 ~~in~~ GF(3^n), ~~n \geq 5 ~~odd$$

See *New families of perfect nonlinear polynomial functions* by
Zhengbang Zha, Xueli Wang, Journal of Algebra (322):3912-3918.

for more. One class of such polynomials are called Dembowski-Ostrom polynomials. All of the above are, but a recent example $$x^{(3^k+1 )/2}$$ isn't.

**Edit:** *I apologise, I shouldn't post before my morning coffee. This is now essentially a long comment.*

*The functions displayed are not involutions. Recent work on involutions is [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.11344). I think your question is quite difficult.*

Comment: You mentioned 
`x^2  \in GF(p^n)` . is it involution for any field of odd characteristic ?

Comment: I need special involutions among perfect nonlinear or differentially 1−uniform functions

Comment: I tried to find these functions last 3 years :)
I was aware about described papers and types of functions.
I know that this question is very difficult :)

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account Peter's Tailor analysis I can say the following.
For example we have finite field $GF(p)$ for $p$ prime;

We can take element $2$ and obtain subgroup generated by $2$: $<2>$.
This subgroup generates set of cosets:

$<2>$, $C_1<2>$ .... $C_{K-1}<2>$

where $k=(|GF^*(p)|/(|<2>|))$.

So exponential functions means that

f($C_i<2>$) = $C_j<2>$

and we have involution of cosets (taking into account that their number is even)

$(i_1,j_1),...,(i_r,j_r)$.

Plus we have the following condition:

for any two cosets $i,j$
if $(a,b)\in C_i<2>$, $(f(a),f(b))\in C_j<2>$

we have: $a/b$=$f(a)/f(b)$.

So we can iterate over all involutions on the set of such Cosets
and iterate over corresponding mapping for each pair of cosets.

Comment: The biggest questions is: how to describe cosets mapping to get such functions.
We dive to the Cyclotomy of Finite Field.

Comment: This is a place where I stuck and can't find solution.

Comment: 3'rd constraint works for

0, 12, 24, 8, 17, 28, 16, 9, 3, 7, 25, 30, 1, 27, 18, 21, 6, 4, 14, 20, 19, 15, 29, 26, 2, 10, 23, 13, 5, 22, 11

Answer (score 0):

$GF(31)$:

all these involutions satisfy all 3 constraints:

0, 12, 24, 8, 17, 28, 16, 9, 3, 7, 25, 30, 1, 27, 18, 21, 6, 4, 14, 20, 19, 15, 29, 26, 2, 10, 23, 13, 5, 22, 11

0, 13, 26, 23, 21, 7, 15, 5, 11, 25, 14, 8, 30, 1, 10, 6, 22, 27, 19, 18, 28, 4, 16, 3, 29, 9, 2, 17, 20, 24, 12

0, 14, 28, 5, 25, 3, 10, 16, 19, 24, 6, 23, 20, 30, 1, 22, 7, 18, 17, 8, 12, 27, 15, 11, 9, 4, 29, 21, 2, 26, 13

0, 18, 5, 29, 10, 2, 27, 22, 20, 16, 4, 19, 23, 14, 13, 24, 9, 30, 1, 11, 8, 25, 7, 12, 15, 21, 28, 6, 26, 3, 17

0, 19, 7, 11, 14, 29, 22, 2, 28, 15, 27, 3, 13, 12, 4, 9, 25, 21, 30, 1, 23, 17, 6, 20, 26, 16, 24, 10, 8, 5, 18

0, 20, 9, 26, 18, 8, 21, 29, 5, 2, 16, 12, 11, 17, 27, 25, 10, 13, 4, 30, 1, 6, 24, 28, 22, 15, 3, 14, 23, 7, 19

Answer (score 0):

$Z/255Z$:

```
    $0, 16, 32, 220, 64, 41, 185, 101, 128, 190, 82, 69, 115, 212, 202, 254, 1, 204, 125, 145, 164, 44, 138, 234, 230, 49, 169, 177, 149, 122, 253, 203, 2, 215, 153, 38, 250, 160, 35, 180, 73, 5, 88, 56, 21, 201, 213, 124, 205, 25, 98, 68, 83, 67, 99, 192, 43, 165, 244, 159, 251, 142, 151, 118, 4, 74, 175, 53, 51, 11, 76, 158, 245, 40, 65, 114, 70, 208, 105, 163, 146, 194, 10, 52, 176, 170, 112, 184, 42, 193, 147, 111, 171, 226, 248, 132, 155, 168, 50, 54, 196, 7, 136, 243, 166, 78, 134, 237, 198, 189, 129, 91, 86, 174, 75, 12, 233, 139, 63, 221, 247, 227, 29, 218, 47, 18, 236, 135, 8, 110, 148, 178, 95, 162, 106, 127, 102, 200, 22, 117, 152, 216, 61, 229, 235, 19, 80, 90, 130, 28, 228, 62, 140, 34, 161, 96, 210, 207, 71, 59, 37, 154, 133, 79, 20, 57, 104, 209, 97, 26, 85, 92, 224, 183, 113, 66, 84, 27, 131, 249, 39, 246, 222, 173, 87, 6, 197, 238, 241, 109, 9, 195, 55, 89, 81, 191, 100, 186, 108, 242, 137, 45, 14, 31, 17, 48, 231, 157, 77, 167, 156, 232, 13, 46, 219, 33, 141, 252, 123, 214, 3, 119, 182, 225, 172, 223, 93, 121, 150, 143, 24, 206, 211, 116, 23, 144, 126, 107, 187, 240, 239, 188, 199, 103, 58, 72, 181, 120, 94, 179, 36, 60, 217, 30, 15$
    $0, 134, 13, 210, 26, 143, 165, 87, 52, 148, 31, 253, 75, 2, 174, 152, 104, 68, 41, 225, 62, 245, 251, 237, 150, 202, 4, 110, 93, 218, 49, 10, 208, 146, 136, 89, 82, 66, 195, 154, 124, 18, 235, 100, 247, 48, 219, 79, 45, 30, 149, 238, 8, 78, 220, 141, 186, 212, 181, 179, 98, 188, 20, 243, 161, 227, 37, 128, 17, 125, 178, 182, 164, 144, 132, 12, 135, 147, 53, 47, 248, 95, 36, 228, 215, 170, 200, 7, 239, 35, 96, 163, 183, 28, 158, 81, 90, 191, 60, 205, 43, 140, 221, 118, 16, 129, 156, 116, 185, 142, 27, 184, 117, 222, 169, 216, 107, 112, 103, 153, 196, 122, 121, 197, 40, 69, 231, 194, 67, 105, 199, 171, 74, 254, 1, 76, 34, 240, 250, 246, 101, 55, 109, 5, 73, 172, 33, 77, 9, 50, 24, 167, 15, 119, 39, 198, 106, 217, 94, 249, 241, 64, 190, 91, 72, 6, 201, 151, 175, 114, 85, 131, 145, 209, 14, 168, 223, 230, 70, 59, 192, 58, 71, 92, 111, 108, 56, 204, 61, 226, 162, 97, 180, 213, 127, 38, 120, 123, 155, 130, 86, 166, 25, 211, 187, 99, 236, 252, 32, 173, 3, 203, 57, 193, 232, 84, 115, 157, 29, 46, 54, 102, 113, 176, 234, 19, 189, 65, 83, 233, 177, 126, 214, 229, 224, 42, 206, 23, 51, 88, 137, 160, 244, 63, 242, 21, 139, 44, 80, 159, 138, 22, 207, 11, 133$
    $0, 13, 26, 191, 52, 71, 127, 89, 104, 235, 142, 176, 254, 1, 178, 186, 208, 68, 215, 220, 29, 81, 97, 183, 253, 177, 2, 145, 101, 20, 117, 74, 161, 125, 136, 54, 175, 143, 185, 179, 58, 124, 162, 224, 194, 167, 111, 63, 251, 205, 99, 238, 4, 109, 35, 196, 202, 157, 40, 114, 234, 105, 148, 47, 67, 209, 250, 64, 17, 84, 108, 5, 95, 227, 31, 233, 115, 91, 103, 90, 116, 21, 248, 214, 69, 170, 193, 225, 133, 7, 79, 77, 222, 135, 126, 72, 247, 22, 155, 50, 198, 28, 221, 78, 8, 61, 218, 169, 70, 53, 137, 46, 149, 123, 59, 76, 80, 30, 228, 153, 213, 249, 210, 113, 41, 33, 94, 6, 134, 223, 163, 172, 245, 88, 128, 93, 34, 110, 168, 219, 216, 200, 10, 37, 190, 27, 199, 217, 62, 112, 211, 159, 230, 119, 182, 98, 206, 57, 180, 151, 232, 32, 42, 130, 241, 244, 173, 45, 138, 107, 85, 240, 131, 166, 195, 36, 11, 25, 14, 39, 158, 212, 154, 23, 189, 38, 15, 204, 252, 184, 144, 3, 239, 86, 44, 174, 55, 237, 100, 146, 141, 236, 56, 207, 187, 49, 156, 203, 16, 65, 122, 150, 181, 120, 83, 18, 140, 147, 106, 139, 19, 102, 92, 129, 43, 87, 246, 73, 118, 231, 152, 229, 160, 75, 60, 9, 201, 197, 51, 192, 171, 164, 243, 242, 165, 132, 226, 96, 82, 121, 66, 48, 188, 24, 12$
    $0, 240, 225, 38, 195, 219, 76, 161, 135, 74, 183, 197, 152, 56, 67, 16, 15, 68, 148, 129, 111, 232, 139, 44, 49, 231, 112, 105, 134, 162, 32, 83, 30, 73, 136, 252, 41, 132, 3, 114, 222, 36, 209, 242, 23, 99, 88, 178, 98, 24, 207, 238, 224, 241, 210, 118, 13, 147, 69, 155, 64, 174, 166, 200, 60, 246, 146, 14, 17, 58, 249, 168, 82, 33, 9, 216, 6, 124, 228, 171, 189, 142, 72, 31, 163, 170, 229, 158, 46, 151, 198, 235, 176, 122, 101, 218, 196, 184, 48, 45, 159, 94, 221, 115, 193, 27, 227, 125, 165, 175, 236, 20, 26, 194, 39, 103, 138, 233, 55, 153, 128, 149, 93, 160, 77, 107, 145, 247, 120, 19, 237, 208, 37, 226, 28, 8, 34, 192, 116, 22, 243, 180, 81, 169, 164, 126, 66, 57, 18, 121, 177, 89, 12, 119, 248, 59, 201, 205, 87, 100, 123, 7, 29, 84, 144, 108, 62, 213, 71, 143, 85, 79, 203, 245, 61, 109, 92, 150, 47, 185, 141, 190, 215, 10, 97, 179, 244, 204, 202, 80, 181, 251, 137, 104, 113, 4, 96, 11, 90, 212, 63, 156, 188, 172, 187, 157, 230, 50, 131, 42, 54, 234, 199, 167, 250, 182, 75, 220, 95, 5, 217, 102, 40, 253, 52, 2, 133, 106, 78, 86, 206, 25, 21, 117, 211, 91, 110, 130, 51, 254, 1, 53, 43, 140, 186, 173, 65, 127, 154, 70, 214, 191, 35, 223, 239$
    $0, 197, 139, 50, 23, 66, 100, 171, 46, 20, 132, 246, 200, 220, 87, 169, 92, 68, 40, 251, 9, 214, 237, 4, 145, 129, 185, 177, 174, 157, 83, 148, 184, 130, 136, 48, 80, 199, 247, 180, 18, 62, 173, 178, 219, 201, 8, 252, 35, 191, 3, 238, 115, 225, 99, 67, 93, 165, 59, 58, 166, 250, 41, 203, 113, 144, 5, 55, 17, 181, 96, 103, 160, 241, 143, 114, 239, 120, 105, 190, 36, 109, 124, 30, 91, 170, 101, 14, 183, 149, 147, 84, 16, 56, 249, 167, 70, 222, 127, 54, 6, 86, 221, 71, 230, 78, 195, 138, 198, 81, 134, 176, 186, 64, 75, 52, 118, 224, 116, 153, 77, 231, 245, 133, 82, 158, 151, 98, 226, 25, 33, 213, 10, 123, 110, 212, 34, 253, 107, 2, 192, 216, 206, 74, 65, 24, 227, 90, 31, 89, 228, 126, 223, 119, 240, 161, 210, 29, 125, 229, 72, 155, 218, 179, 248, 57, 60, 95, 182, 15, 85, 7, 202, 42, 28, 211, 111, 27, 43, 163, 39, 69, 168, 88, 32, 26, 112, 204, 243, 194, 79, 49, 140, 234, 189, 106, 254, 1, 108, 37, 12, 45, 172, 63, 187, 208, 142, 242, 205, 217, 156, 175, 135, 131, 21, 233, 141, 209, 162, 44, 13, 102, 97, 152, 117, 53, 128, 146, 150, 159, 104, 121, 236, 215, 193, 244, 232, 22, 51, 76, 154, 73, 207, 188, 235, 122, 11, 38, 164, 94, 61, 19, 47, 137, 196$
    $0, 23, 46, 106, 92, 36, 212, 222, 184, 65, 72, 127, 169, 70, 189, 186, 113, 204, 130, 178, 144, 81, 254, 1, 83, 52, 140, 230, 123, 61, 117, 250, 226, 40, 153, 134, 5, 210, 101, 94, 33, 150, 162, 49, 253, 82, 2, 147, 166, 43, 104, 68, 25, 129, 205, 216, 246, 242, 122, 231, 234, 29, 245, 217, 197, 9, 80, 145, 51, 84, 13, 79, 10, 180, 165, 148, 202, 96, 188, 71, 66, 21, 45, 24, 69, 170, 98, 225, 251, 137, 164, 181, 4, 135, 39, 227, 77, 239, 86, 220, 208, 38, 136, 252, 50, 146, 3, 182, 155, 214, 177, 131, 237, 16, 229, 141, 244, 30, 207, 221, 213, 156, 58, 28, 235, 143, 179, 11, 139, 53, 18, 111, 160, 191, 35, 93, 102, 89, 168, 128, 26, 115, 158, 125, 20, 67, 105, 47, 75, 152, 41, 201, 149, 34, 192, 108, 121, 243, 142, 236, 132, 200, 42, 167, 90, 74, 48, 163, 138, 12, 85, 240, 196, 218, 195, 241, 247, 110, 19, 126, 73, 91, 107, 193, 8, 198, 15, 238, 78, 14, 199, 133, 154, 183, 223, 174, 172, 64, 185, 190, 161, 151, 76, 228, 17, 54, 249, 118, 100, 211, 37, 209, 6, 120, 109, 248, 55, 63, 173, 224, 99, 119, 7, 194, 219, 87, 32, 95, 203, 114, 27, 59, 233, 232, 60, 124, 159, 112, 187, 97, 171, 175, 57, 157, 116, 62, 56, 176, 215, 206, 31, 88, 103, 44, 22$
    $0, 25, 50, 223, 100, 138, 191, 112, 200, 120, 21, 245, 127, 99, 224, 33, 145, 68, 240, 92, 42, 10, 235, 196, 254, 1, 198, 104, 193, 181, 66, 45, 35, 15, 136, 32, 225, 179, 184, 106, 84, 157, 20, 121, 215, 31, 137, 101, 253, 197, 2, 238, 141, 147, 208, 63, 131, 83, 107, 82, 132, 186, 90, 55, 70, 162, 30, 216, 17, 130, 64, 109, 195, 236, 103, 199, 113, 228, 212, 174, 168, 160, 59, 57, 40, 170, 242, 167, 175, 203, 62, 209, 19, 158, 202, 176, 251, 190, 139, 13, 4, 47, 221, 74, 27, 248, 39, 58, 161, 71, 126, 246, 7, 76, 166, 243, 214, 122, 164, 153, 9, 43, 117, 183, 180, 194, 110, 12, 140, 239, 69, 56, 60, 250, 177, 144, 34, 46, 5, 98, 128, 52, 218, 150, 135, 16, 217, 53, 206, 188, 143, 178, 226, 119, 201, 159, 169, 41, 93, 155, 81, 108, 65, 182, 118, 227, 114, 87, 80, 156, 85, 211, 229, 232, 79, 88, 95, 134, 151, 37, 124, 29, 163, 123, 38, 249, 61, 204, 149, 219, 97, 6, 247, 28, 125, 72, 23, 49, 26, 75, 8, 154, 94, 89, 187, 207, 148, 205, 54, 91, 241, 171, 78, 233, 116, 44, 67, 146, 142, 189, 252, 102, 237, 3, 14, 36, 152, 165, 77, 172, 231, 230, 173, 213, 244, 22, 73, 222, 51, 129, 18, 210, 86, 115, 234, 11, 111, 192, 105, 185, 133, 96, 220, 48, 24$
    $0, 99, 198, 205, 141, 87, 155, 158, 27, 144, 174, 67, 55, 44, 61, 237, 54, 68, 33, 247, 93, 181, 134, 165, 110, 154, 88, 8, 122, 209, 219, 242, 108, 18, 136, 83, 66, 175, 239, 103, 186, 125, 107, 243, 13, 184, 75, 241, 220, 127, 53, 238, 176, 50, 16, 12, 244, 59, 163, 57, 183, 14, 229, 178, 216, 213, 36, 11, 17, 109, 166, 116, 132, 235, 95, 46, 223, 140, 206, 131, 117, 91, 250, 35, 214, 170, 231, 5, 26, 159, 113, 81, 150, 20, 227, 74, 185, 104, 254, 1, 106, 126, 221, 39, 97, 197, 100, 42, 32, 69, 24, 120, 233, 90, 118, 192, 71, 80, 114, 153, 111, 143, 28, 195, 203, 41, 101, 49, 177, 230, 171, 79, 72, 161, 22, 246, 34, 251, 218, 210, 77, 4, 232, 121, 9, 169, 215, 179, 190, 249, 92, 248, 191, 119, 25, 6, 157, 156, 7, 89, 234, 133, 182, 58, 245, 23, 70, 193, 173, 145, 85, 130, 207, 168, 10, 37, 52, 128, 63, 147, 226, 21, 162, 60, 45, 96, 40, 204, 199, 225, 148, 152, 115, 167, 208, 123, 253, 105, 2, 188, 212, 217, 252, 124, 187, 3, 78, 172, 194, 29, 139, 224, 200, 65, 84, 146, 64, 201, 138, 30, 48, 102, 240, 76, 211, 189, 180, 94, 236, 62, 129, 86, 142, 112, 160, 73, 228, 15, 51, 38, 222, 47, 31, 43, 56, 164, 135, 19, 151, 149, 82, 137, 202, 196, 98$
    $0, 141, 27, 48, 54, 92, 96, 79, 108, 31, 184, 123, 192, 208, 158, 203, 216, 68, 62, 173, 113, 116, 246, 65, 129, 253, 161, 2, 61, 69, 151, 9, 177, 227, 136, 191, 124, 86, 91, 55, 226, 178, 232, 146, 237, 252, 130, 60, 3, 218, 251, 238, 67, 217, 4, 39, 122, 185, 138, 166, 47, 28, 18, 75, 99, 23, 199, 52, 17, 29, 127, 81, 248, 149, 172, 63, 182, 118, 110, 7, 197, 71, 101, 157, 209, 170, 37, 250, 219, 148, 249, 38, 5, 235, 120, 234, 6, 111, 181, 64, 247, 82, 221, 212, 134, 231, 179, 196, 8, 152, 78, 97, 244, 20, 115, 114, 21, 175, 77, 153, 94, 225, 56, 11, 36, 171, 150, 70, 198, 24, 46, 167, 143, 189, 104, 229, 34, 214, 58, 160, 254, 1, 162, 132, 241, 223, 43, 155, 89, 73, 126, 30, 109, 119, 236, 147, 220, 83, 14, 165, 139, 26, 142, 168, 202, 159, 59, 131, 163, 206, 85, 125, 74, 19, 245, 117, 183, 32, 41, 106, 243, 98, 76, 176, 10, 57, 215, 204, 240, 133, 213, 35, 12, 211, 222, 242, 107, 80, 128, 66, 239, 205, 164, 15, 187, 201, 169, 210, 13, 84, 207, 193, 103, 190, 137, 186, 16, 53, 49, 88, 156, 102, 194, 145, 233, 121, 40, 33, 230, 135, 228, 105, 42, 224, 95, 93, 154, 44, 51, 200, 188, 144, 195, 180, 112, 174, 22, 100, 72, 90, 87, 50, 45, 25, 140$
    $0, 115, 230, 210, 205, 168, 165, 183, 155, 233, 81, 143, 75, 60, 111, 67, 55, 204, 211, 101, 162, 160, 31, 213, 150, 27, 120, 25, 222, 215, 134, 22, 110, 61, 153, 99, 167, 206, 202, 239, 69, 118, 65, 152, 62, 48, 171, 242, 45, 86, 54, 68, 240, 91, 50, 16, 189, 127, 175, 148, 13, 33, 44, 243, 220, 42, 122, 15, 51, 40, 198, 245, 79, 179, 157, 12, 149, 214, 223, 72, 138, 10, 236, 181, 130, 170, 49, 92, 124, 196, 96, 53, 87, 113, 229, 116, 90, 241, 172, 35, 108, 19, 136, 146, 225, 129, 182, 166, 100, 212, 32, 14, 123, 93, 254, 1, 95, 197, 41, 221, 26, 151, 66, 112, 88, 209, 231, 57, 185, 105, 84, 219, 244, 199, 30, 161, 102, 178, 80, 234, 141, 140, 235, 11, 158, 177, 103, 247, 59, 76, 24, 121, 43, 34, 173, 8, 191, 74, 144, 249, 21, 135, 20, 250, 217, 6, 107, 36, 5, 218, 85, 46, 98, 154, 184, 58, 248, 145, 137, 73, 192, 83, 106, 7, 174, 128, 226, 238, 203, 56, 232, 156, 180, 237, 227, 208, 89, 117, 70, 133, 216, 251, 38, 188, 17, 4, 37, 252, 195, 125, 3, 18, 109, 23, 77, 29, 200, 164, 169, 131, 64, 119, 28, 78, 246, 104, 186, 194, 253, 94, 2, 126, 190, 9, 139, 142, 82, 193, 187, 39, 52, 97, 47, 63, 132, 71, 224, 147, 176, 159, 163, 201, 207, 228, 114$
    $0, 157, 59, 53, 118, 173, 106, 104, 236, 120, 91, 199, 212, 224, 208, 33, 217, 204, 240, 27, 182, 95, 143, 113, 169, 126, 193, 19, 161, 75, 66, 44, 179, 15, 153, 207, 225, 117, 54, 191, 109, 171, 190, 55, 31, 116, 226, 61, 83, 177, 252, 68, 131, 3, 38, 43, 67, 253, 150, 2, 132, 47, 88, 140, 103, 107, 30, 56, 51, 215, 159, 210, 195, 93, 234, 29, 108, 192, 127, 203, 218, 245, 87, 48, 125, 170, 110, 82, 62, 185, 232, 10, 197, 73, 122, 21, 166, 248, 99, 98, 249, 230, 136, 64, 7, 163, 6, 65, 76, 40, 86, 246, 134, 23, 251, 178, 45, 37, 4, 221, 9, 233, 94, 183, 176, 84, 25, 78, 206, 154, 214, 52, 60, 227, 112, 144, 102, 141, 175, 184, 63, 137, 165, 22, 135, 231, 186, 223, 213, 155, 58, 158, 216, 34, 129, 149, 254, 1, 151, 70, 181, 28, 235, 105, 174, 142, 96, 229, 250, 24, 85, 41, 220, 5, 164, 138, 124, 49, 115, 32, 209, 160, 20, 123, 139, 89, 146, 238, 244, 219, 42, 39, 77, 26, 241, 72, 198, 92, 196, 11, 243, 239, 205, 79, 17, 202, 128, 35, 14, 180, 71, 242, 12, 148, 130, 69, 152, 16, 80, 189, 172, 119, 237, 147, 13, 36, 46, 133, 247, 167, 101, 145, 90, 121, 74, 162, 8, 222, 187, 201, 18, 194, 211, 200, 188, 81, 111, 228, 97, 100, 168, 114, 50, 57, 156$
    $0, 59, 118, 208, 236, 194, 161, 91, 217, 244, 133, 20, 67, 48, 182, 101, 179, 204, 233, 23, 11, 62, 40, 19, 134, 151, 96, 105, 109, 127, 202, 138, 103, 158, 153, 242, 211, 93, 46, 114, 22, 234, 124, 120, 80, 99, 38, 50, 13, 113, 47, 68, 192, 83, 210, 243, 218, 147, 254, 1, 149, 66, 21, 115, 206, 176, 61, 12, 51, 143, 229, 223, 167, 87, 186, 216, 92, 212, 228, 144, 44, 227, 213, 53, 248, 170, 240, 73, 160, 195, 198, 7, 76, 37, 100, 183, 26, 130, 226, 45, 94, 15, 136, 32, 129, 27, 166, 224, 165, 28, 231, 190, 181, 49, 39, 63, 253, 148, 2, 221, 43, 145, 132, 245, 42, 222, 230, 29, 157, 104, 97, 173, 122, 10, 24, 178, 102, 139, 31, 137, 203, 180, 191, 69, 79, 121, 174, 57, 117, 60, 177, 25, 184, 34, 169, 249, 201, 128, 33, 185, 88, 6, 199, 239, 171, 108, 106, 72, 241, 154, 85, 164, 225, 131, 146, 219, 65, 150, 135, 16, 141, 112, 14, 95, 152, 159, 74, 238, 200, 250, 111, 142, 52, 214, 5, 89, 197, 196, 90, 162, 188, 156, 30, 140, 17, 252, 64, 220, 3, 247, 54, 36, 77, 82, 193, 237, 75, 8, 56, 175, 207, 119, 125, 71, 107, 172, 98, 81, 78, 70, 126, 110, 251, 18, 41, 246, 4, 215, 187, 163, 86, 168, 35, 55, 9, 123, 235, 209, 84, 155, 189, 232, 205, 116, 58$
    $0, 122, 244, 48, 233, 117, 96, 175, 211, 116, 234, 13, 192, 11, 95, 118, 167, 204, 232, 49, 213, 31, 26, 41, 129, 78, 22, 172, 190, 66, 236, 21, 79, 142, 153, 201, 209, 226, 98, 140, 171, 23, 62, 198, 52, 252, 82, 223, 3, 19, 156, 68, 44, 230, 89, 169, 125, 100, 132, 135, 217, 128, 42, 75, 158, 93, 29, 194, 51, 199, 147, 144, 163, 184, 197, 63, 196, 185, 25, 32, 87, 241, 46, 110, 124, 170, 141, 80, 104, 54, 249, 183, 164, 65, 191, 14, 6, 161, 38, 149, 57, 216, 136, 240, 88, 231, 205, 246, 178, 222, 83, 182, 250, 146, 200, 154, 9, 5, 15, 221, 179, 254, 1, 181, 84, 56, 150, 188, 61, 24, 186, 215, 58, 134, 133, 59, 102, 152, 143, 148, 39, 86, 33, 138, 71, 228, 113, 70, 139, 99, 126, 239, 137, 34, 115, 212, 50, 195, 64, 165, 174, 97, 227, 72, 92, 159, 220, 16, 248, 55, 85, 40, 27, 219, 160, 7, 208, 202, 108, 120, 243, 123, 111, 91, 73, 77, 130, 238, 127, 218, 28, 94, 12, 235, 67, 157, 76, 74, 43, 69, 114, 35, 177, 247, 17, 106, 225, 210, 176, 36, 207, 8, 155, 20, 237, 131, 101, 60, 189, 173, 166, 119, 109, 47, 245, 206, 37, 162, 145, 251, 53, 105, 18, 4, 10, 193, 30, 214, 187, 151, 103, 81, 253, 180, 2, 224, 107, 203, 168, 90, 112, 229, 45, 242, 121$
    $0, 233, 211, 152, 167, 224, 49, 40, 79, 199, 193, 139, 98, 198, 80, 84, 158, 68, 143, 96, 131, 195, 23, 22, 196, 228, 141, 52, 160, 223, 168, 36, 61, 248, 136, 156, 31, 82, 192, 200, 7, 146, 135, 249, 46, 218, 44, 155, 137, 6, 201, 238, 27, 179, 104, 94, 65, 70, 191, 83, 81, 32, 72, 101, 122, 56, 241, 177, 17, 240, 57, 247, 62, 148, 164, 182, 129, 236, 145, 8, 14, 60, 37, 59, 15, 170, 243, 117, 92, 207, 181, 165, 88, 213, 55, 123, 19, 113, 12, 134, 147, 63, 221, 106, 54, 214, 103, 180, 208, 150, 188, 235, 130, 97, 140, 229, 127, 87, 166, 153, 162, 220, 64, 95, 144, 237, 202, 116, 244, 76, 112, 20, 227, 197, 99, 42, 34, 48, 225, 11, 114, 26, 239, 18, 124, 78, 41, 100, 73, 252, 109, 205, 3, 119, 217, 47, 35, 169, 16, 178, 28, 216, 120, 251, 74, 91, 118, 4, 30, 157, 85, 186, 231, 210, 234, 189, 184, 67, 159, 53, 107, 90, 75, 245, 176, 242, 171, 204, 110, 175, 246, 58, 38, 10, 226, 21, 24, 133, 13, 9, 39, 50, 126, 230, 187, 151, 212, 89, 108, 253, 173, 2, 206, 93, 105, 222, 161, 154, 45, 250, 121, 102, 215, 29, 5, 138, 194, 132, 25, 115, 203, 172, 254, 1, 174, 111, 77, 125, 51, 142, 69, 66, 185, 86, 128, 183, 190, 71, 33, 43, 219, 163, 149, 209, 232$
```

Comment: Since $255$ is not a prime power (so that $\mathbb Z / (255)$ is not a field), it is not clear what this post has to do with the question.

Comment: It mean that people found such involutions not only for fields but also for Rings (which are not Fields)

Answer (score 0):

The perfect nonlinear function $f$ can be represented as a special sequence ($a_{1},...,a_{n}$).

The main property: $f(a_{i}) = a_{-i}$.

Other properties:

${a_{2^k}}$ = $2^k$;

There exist such element $\alpha$ that

${a_{-i} = a_{i} + i*(\alpha-1)}$

For $i \ne 0, i+1 \ne 0$ we have:

$ f(a_{i}) - f(a_{i}-a_{i+1}) = 1$

For any 2 not equal $i,k \ne 0, i+k \ne 0 $:

$ f(a_{i}) - f(a_{i}-a_{i+k}) = a_{k}$

I know yet 5 of the same nature sequences for the $GF(31)$.

I know a sequence of the same nature for the $GF(2^{k}-1)$ and prime $2^{k}-1$.

Looks like the following property holds as well:

$
a_{j} - a_{k} = a_{j+ \frac{a_{k}-a_{k-j}}{\alpha-1}}
$

$
 a_{i} = -f(i*(\alpha-1))
$

Example ($\alpha=18$):

> ```
> |index   |  value |
> |--------| -------|
> |0       |   0    | 
> |1       |   1    |
> |2       |   2    | 
> |3       |   23   |
> |4       |   4    |
> |5       |   19   |
> |6       |   15   |
> |7       |   3    |
> |8       |   8    |
> |9       |   28   |
> |10      |   7    |
> |11      |   13   |
> |12      |   30   |
> |13      |   21   |
> |14      |   6    |
> |15      |   9    |
> |16      |   16   |
> |17      |   27   |
> |18      |   25   |
> |19      |   17   |
> |20      |   14   |
> |21      |   22   |
> |22      |   26   |
> |23      |   20   |
> |24      |   29   |
> |25      |   24   |
> |26      |   11   |
> |27      |   10   |
> |28      |   12   |
> |29      |   5    |
> |30      |   18   |
> --------------------
> ```

Comment: It is extremely hard to understand your post: you make claims that you do not prove, and you claim to know results that you do not share with us. What is the point of your answer, then?

Comment: I spent many intellectual efforts to obtain these results, probably it would be interesting for the scientific society.

Comment: I still hope to get some help and will finally discover the nature of these perfect non-linear involutive functions.

Comment: BTW: I was an author of the original question (another temporary user)

Comment: quite frankly I had a strong suspicion that you and the OP are connected, possibly the same person: the same LaTeX and graphical style, the same vocabulary, many other similarities. Please notice that, currently, the OP has written 3 posts that are not answers, to which I would add yours (which, again, is not an answer). If I were you or the OP, I would collect the useful information from all these 4 posts into a single one, and delete the other 3.

Comment: Our conversation is out of the Math.
I prefer mathematical discussions about science.