# Chains of numbers generated by 2 involutions

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

$\DeclareMathOperator\GF{GF}$Consider the finite field $\GF(p)$ for prime $p$.

Consider the pair of involutions $f(x) = 1-x$ , $g(x) = 1/x$, and the chain of numbers generated by these 2 involutions in the following way:
$$\cdots f(g(f(x))) \leftarrow g(f(x)) \leftarrow  f(x) \to  x  \to g(x) \to f(g(x) \to g(f(g(x)) \cdots$$

Apparently the maximal length of this chain for specific $x$ is equal to 6.

Could you please explain if this construction has some special name in mathematics, or was studied in the theory of finite fields?

For example for $\GF(31)$ we have:

\begin{gather*}
12 \leftarrow 20 \leftarrow 14  \to 18 \to 19 \to 13 \to 12 \\
12, 13, 14, 18, 19, 20.
\end{gather*}

Comment: These two involutions generate a group of order 6 isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_3$ (this is true over any field $k$, viewing these two involutions acting on the projective line $\mathbb{P}^1(k)$). This corresponds to the different values of the cross-ratio when you permute the arguments: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio#Six_cross-ratios

Comment: Can one not prove by just plugging in and doing the algebra that $f(g(f(x)))=g(f(g(x)))$?

Comment: Cross-ratio can be used in finite field as well

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Correct, and I think you should post that as an answer.

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer.

Comment: Since it hasn't been said so far, the set of numbers one obtains from $x$ is called the *orbit* of $x$ under the group generated by $\{f,g\}$.

Comment: please do not vandalize the question, it has received an answer which would make no sense if the question is deleted.

Comment: This is a site for questions of math research, @AVT. The $-2$ probably came from users  who feel your question had no research angle. There's a fair chance that at some point other users will vote to close it, and then to delete it. Or, maybe not; maybe users will feel the answer redeems the question. But in any event, vandalizing the question is a significant breach of this website's norms. Please don't do it.

Comment: This question was born as a result of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338802/finite-field-special-functions research. 
12 13 14 18 19 20 - coefficients which move Finited Field's cosets and give us corresponding Finite Field's involution.

Comment: I suspect that may be cross ratios could help to investigate that involution's nature.

Answer (score 4):

The involutions $x \to 1-x$ and $x \to 1/x$ generate a group of order 6 isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_3$. This is true over any field $k$, viewing these two involutions acting on the projective line $\mathbb{P}^1(k)$. One way to see this: these involutions leave stable $\{0,1,\infty\}$, and any linear fractional transformation of $\mathbb{P}^1(k)$ is determined uniquely by its action on $0,1,\infty$.

This group also reflects the different values of the cross-ratio when you permute the arguments: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio#Six_cross-ratios

Comment: Great answer !!!

Cross ratios - was the abstraction I was looking for.
Thanks.