# Related involutions

Tags: finite-fields, involutions

Let's say that we have finite field $\mathbb F_q$ and we have a couple of involutions $g,f$ with exactly one fixed point (zero).

Let's take any element $\alpha \in \mathbb F_q$
Let's start applying involutions to this element in the following way:
$$ \ldots f(g(\alpha)) \ldots g(\alpha) \ldots \alpha \ldots f(\alpha) \ldots g(f(\alpha)) \ldots $$
Let's imagine that on some step the element on the left side become equal to the element on the right side for any $\alpha$.

What is the name for such couple of involutions with this property ?

Are there any theorems regarding existence of such couple of involutions ?

The example of such couple of involutions is here: [Chains of numbers generated by 2 involutions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373232/chains-of-numbers-generated-by-2-involutions?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: The most important question is:

Let's $f=1/x$, how to find all corresponding $g$

Comment: If I am reading your question correctly, isn't it the case that any pair of involutions have this property. There are only finitely many permutations of $\mathbb{F}_{q}$. Hence for some $n$, we have that $(fg)^{n}$ is the identity permutation. Then $(gf)^{n}$ is also the identity permutation, since $gf = g(fg)g^{-1}.$

Comment: Correct, you are right.

Comment: I suggest to close question.

Comment: The interesting questions here is about $n$ and $q=2^k-1$.

Found couple of involutions when $n | (q-1)/k$